# Scala method that returns the first string found in the alphabet/dictionary

Tags: string, scala, alphabetical

For example this code

```
val stringTuple = ("BLACK", "GRAY", "WHITE")
firstInAlphabet(stringTuple)
```

Should return `"BLACK"`. How would you define `firstInAlphabet`?

Personally I prefer simple and fast implementations over complicated ones that would cover a lot of cases.

Comment: In most cases, treating your tuple as containing a sequence instead is a design smell

Comment: If the tuple is already ordered as you state in the headline, simply call `tuple._1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t.productIterator.map(_.asInstanceOf[String]).min
```

`productIterator` converts the elements of the tuple to an iterator. This looses the type information, so we have to cast the elements and then we use min to find the first.

If you have non-String elements in your tuple this version should do the trick:

```
t.productIterator.map(_.toString).min
```

instead of casting to String it converts to a String.

Comment: This will throw if your tuple contains any non-string elements. Otherwise very nice and concise.

Comment: @jwvh correct, added a version that uses string conversion.